# Suppress AWS SDK v2 deprecation message

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am seeing an awful lot of this message:

> NOTE: The AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) will be put into maintenance mode in 2023.
>
> Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
> For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Is it possible to suppress it?

(It's not my code base, so out of my control to upgrade to v3).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best way to suppress this warning (as documented by AWS) is to use an environment variable like so:

```js
process.env.AWS_SDK_JS_SUPPRESS_MAINTENANCE_MODE_MESSAGE = '1';
```

OR

```bash
AWS_SDK_JS_SUPPRESS_MAINTENANCE_MODE_MESSAGE=1 node my_program.js
```

Source:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/

Answer (score 11):

I grepped the AWS SDK code and this seems to work. I feel something like this should documented as a part of the warning message.

```js
require('aws-sdk/lib/maintenance_mode_message').suppress = true;
```

Comment: I'm using the tools through the CLI though - no access to Node code.

Answer (score 4):

Pinning the SDK version to 2.1311.0 removes the deprecation warning.

Credit: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/11753#issuecomment-1433733188

Comment: Thanks, this one is outside my control in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Just import aws-sdk like this

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
require("aws-sdk/lib/maintenance_mode_message").suppress = true;
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/720bc9ff1bf3be5c4478365fef1fc98be70a5d76

can see change they have made here